# mount error: Permission denied

Tags: mount

I'm trying to share a folder in my Windows server to my Ubuntu server.

and I am getting the following error when I issue the command **mount -a**

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

inside **/etc/fstab**

```
//192.168.100.34/Shared/Files /home/user/files        cifs    guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8   0       0
```

The folder being shared from Windows has `RWX` set permission and the firewall is being disabled (for now).

The folder inside the Ubuntu server is `chmod 777`

Comment: If you navigate to *//192.168.100.34/Shared/Files* using Nautilus, are you asked to login with a password?  If so, you need to add a credentials file.

Comment: Thanks, sir. I didnt knew that windows server by default requires `domain/username/password` for shared folders.

Comment: Hey now!  You didn't even upvote my comment!  :P  I'm glad you were able to figure it out.  Best of luck.